# SAPUI5 fill list from model.read

Tags: json, list, model, sapui5

I'm new on SAPUI5 development.

I'm trying to fill a List from dymanic value.

View:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="porcoporcodio.controller.View1" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic"
xmlns:m="sap.m" xmlns:footerbar="sap.ushell.ui.footerbar" xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:commons="sap.suite.ui.commons" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form">
<App>
    <pages>
        <Page title="{i18n>title}">
            <f:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormChange354" minWidth="1024" maxContainerCols="3" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" title="Voli"
                labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4" columnsL="1" columnsM="1" class="editableForm">
                <f:content>
                    <Label id="pene" text="Seleziona Compagnia Aerea " labelFor="combo1"></Label>
                    <ComboBox id="combo1" items="{/CarrierCollection}" selectionChange="onSelectionComboBox" showSecondaryValues= "true">
                        <core:ListItem key="{carrid}" text="{carrid}" additionalText = "{CARRNAME}" />
                    </ComboBox>
                    <Text id="Texto" >

                    </Text>
                </f:content>
            </f:SimpleForm>
<List id="lineItemsList"    items="{
  path: '/flightDetails'
                         }">
    <items>
        <StandardListItem
            title="{carrid}"
            description="{connid}"
        />
    </items>
</List>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

Controller:

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"

  ], function(Controller) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("porcoporcodio.controller.View1", {

    onInit: function() {
        var sServiceUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT/";
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel({
            serviceUrl: "/sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT/"
        });
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    },

    onSelectionComboBox: function(oEvent) {
        var pene = oEvent.getParameter("selectedItem");
        pene = pene ? pene.getText() : pene;
        var oView = this.getView();
        var sPath = "/CarrierCollection('" + pene + "')";
        var oObject = oView.getModel().getObject(sPath);
        var oTexto = oView.byId('Texto');
        oTexto.setText(oObject.CARRNAME);
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel({
            serviceUrl: "/sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT/"
        });
        var oStandardListItem = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
            title: "{carrid}",
            description: "{connid}"
        });
        oModel.read(sPath + "/carrierFlights", {
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                sap.m.MessageToast.show("fgfgfg");
                var json1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                json1.setData({
                    carrierFlights: data
                });
                var oList = oView.byId('lineItemsList');
                oList.setModel(json1);
                oList.bindAggregation("items", "/carrierFlights", oStandardListItem);
            },
            error: function() {
                sap.m.MessageToast.show("veveveeve");
            }
        });
      }
  });
});
```

oModel.read looks like working, indise data i can see my record, but in List show nothing

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ePP5.png) with data.

[My model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUXHK.png)

Really thanks for help.

Comment: Can you add your data?

Comment: added image with data

Comment: Not enough. Do you have data layout example? As for example I sent you in my answer (aData).

Comment: @Jaro thanks, sure i edited my question with image of my model

Comment: I edited my question based on your model.

Comment: @Jaro thanks  again, but don't work. i edited my question with full view and controller code.

Comment: sorry for delay, no way to make works the table binding

Answer (score 2):

You should change:

```
<List id="lineItemsList" items="{path: '/carrierFlights'}">
```

to:

```
<List id="lineItemsList" items="{path: '/flightDetails'}">
```

Also:

```
oList.bindAggregation("items", "/carrierFlights", oStandardListItem);
```

to:

```
oList.bindAggregation("items", "/flightDetails", oStandardListItem);
```

I made simple [demo](http://jsbin.com/noqebaqofi/1/edit?html,output) for you.